# QEMU and FVP models difference

Tags: arm, trace, qemu, fast-model, fvp

Does anyone know what the difference is between ARM's Fixed Virtual Platform (FVP) binaries (which *usually* need a paid license) and QEMU's free models?

For example: which are their strong/weak points such as capabilities for debugging and tracing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say that, even though they can be compared, they should not as they are aimed at different purposes. Note that the terms used here are defined in [DS-5 : What is FVP, RTSM, Foundation Model, AEM model, Fast Model, CADI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31982849/ds-5-what-is-fvp-rtsm-foundation-model-aem-model-fast-model-cadi)) as you specified FVP and fastmodel.

I will try to answer based on what I tried on those tools.

**Speed versus accuracy.**

---

QEMU is less accurate but faster than FVP. There are plenty of different sources about this (even though I could not get a paper about benchmark) but I observed that QEMU is x2 faster than fastmodel for booting Linux.

About accuracy: if you only want to run applications, then QEMU is for you. However if you want to get the micro-architecture (what is inside a core, understand the security extensions,..) then fastmodel is needed. If you need to have access to new extensions/updates of the processors then fastmodel will be the first one to have those functionalities. Probably even before the silicon is available as it is developed within Arm.

**Support**

---

QEMU is open-source so you get the community to help you or even dig into the code. Whereas Arm has a support "hotline" and you cannot get access to the code.

Both have a lot of documentation on how to use the tool and is quite easy to find.

Both run on Windows/Linux.

**Functionality**

---

QEMU also gives the possibility to run `qemu-static` (see the package in Ubuntu,..) and [this page](https://wiki.debian.org/QemuUserEmulation) that gives an overview on it. Fastmodel does not offer this functionality.

I could not find within QEMU how to update the configuration of the system with the same granularity like it is [done within FVP](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.100966_1160_00_en/jka1397225073230.html).

**Creating new SoC**

---

System Canvas can be used within Fastmodel (see [Documentation](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.100965_1160_00_en/rob1371045407361.html)) which is a graphical interface that can be used to generate a SoC.

Within QEMU, it seems that there are some [predefined platforms](https://wiki.qemu.org/Documentation/Platforms/ARM) you can use. While using a FVP, there are listed in [here](https://developer.arm.com/tools-and-software/simulation-models/fixed-virtual-platforms).

**Debug**

---

QEMU seems to only offer GDB as debugger (https://wiki.qemu.org/Documentation/Debugging). FVP can be used with [CADI](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.100966_1160_00_en/jka1397225073230.html), GDB, ModelDebugger. It seems to give more information using Arm debugger about the components of the system.